# How to make a shallower classification tree with OK score?

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I'm new to Phyton and I wish to understand how I can shallow my classification tree maintaining an OK score.

I have a data file with Survived, Sex, Age, and Class from a boat that sunk.
I created a classification tree that predicted whether a passenger should survive or not based on 'Sex', 'Age', and 'Class'.  To do this I converted the 'Sex'-column into a numeric value and removed all the rows in the dataset where 'Age' was missing.

this is what I coded so far, the dataset and my decision tree:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zceRX.png
[2]: https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/alexholt/python-big-data/-/blob/master/data/titanic.csv

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier  
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
from sklearn import tree

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', sep= ',')
print("6.\n" + str(df.head()))

cleanup_nums = {"Sex": {"male": 1, "female": 0},}

df.replace(cleanup_nums, inplace=True)

df = df[df['Age'].notnull()]
[enter image description here][1]
print(df.head(10))

y = df['Survived']
X = df.drop('Survived', axis=1)
print(X.head())

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_impurity_decrease=0.01, max_depth=5)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train) 

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test) 
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

dotfile = open("./dtree1.dot", 'w')
ditfile = tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file = dotfile, feature_names = X.columns, class_names=['Survived','Not Survived'])

dotfile.close()
```

Comment: Really depends on what you consider an OK score. But in general you can reduce the depth of a tree using something like `max_depth` or `min_samples_leaf` but this comes at a cost of potentially underfitting because you're removing some potentially important correlations.

Comment: Thanks @pavel 
I was getting with these a 0.78 score (which is OK for me). I would consider something Ok not that far from what I already obtained. 
I tried with max_depth=4 and obtained a better score (0.87).

Now, with min_samples_leaf I am curious where could I put that in my code?

Comment: Both these options are parameters of DecisionTreeClassifier, but you normally use one or the other. Specifically, `min_samples_leaf` is to ensure you have adequate sample support for each of leaf nodes, but it depends on how many you consider "adequate". I usually set it around 5-10 depending on how big of a dataset I have.